# how to read a video file placed at server in php - video file's name includes http wrapper

Tags: php, video, fseek

I am using the following code but there appears to be warning with `fseek` and returns -1 instead of 0.

```
$file = fopen("http://www.example.com/public_html/data/video/temp.mov", "r") or exit("unable to open file");
fseek($file, -128, SEEK_END);
```

The file gets opened definately but `fseek` doesn't work. Is there some other method to read video from server?

Following is the error message

```
Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for 

Warning: fseek() [function.fseek]: stream does not support seeking in
```

Comment: form PHP Note: May not be used on file pointers returned by fopen() if they use the "http://" or "ftp://" formats. fseek() gives also undefined results for append-only streams (opened with "a" flag).

Comment: OP's filename does NOT use http wrapper.

Comment: As it turns out (after comments and edits), it is indeed about HTTP wrappers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be some platform dependant problem. Try this code:

```
$filename = "www.example.com/public_html/data/video/temp.mov";
$file = fopen ($filename, "r")
    or exit("unable to open file");
fseek ($file, filesize ($filename) - 128);
```

HTTP wrapper does not support seeking. If you want to seek in a remote file thru HTTP you need to get the size of the file. One possible way is to interpret a directory listing, or make a `HEAD` request. When you know the filesize you can use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and [Range like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460992/resumable-and-partial-download-with-php-curl-or-similar/5461171#5461171).

This is also a method to [get remote file size](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1207).

How to download a file with cURL (This example loads the data into a PHP variable, use only if you want to process the data, If you just want to save it into an external file use CURLOPT_FILE instead of CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER):

```
$c = curl_init (); 
curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/some_dir/some_file.ext"); 
curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_RANGE, max (0, $filesize - 128) . '-' . max (0, $filesize - 1));
curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec ();
echo ($content);
```

Comment: didn't work. same error message appears. warning with filesize and fseek.

Comment: @Kiara If there is an error message please add it to you question.

Comment: @Kiara Are you opening local files of thru a network? For your example I guesses it was a local file, but not beeing to seek makes it likely that you use HTTP wrapper like `http://example.com/data/...`

Comment: @Kiara If you are using HTTP wrapper then it's a completely different story. You should've written it at the first place. I edited my answer, please edit your question b including the "http://".

Comment: @vbence: Thanx a lot. I got the filesize now but could you please tell me how to use this curl or range function. I tried to read its documentation but could not get much. I am newbie in php u knw :)

Comment: @Kiara I added a cURL example.

Comment: @Kiara Feel free to vote up answers you find useful any time.

Comment: For the genius with the -1: please leave a comment, so I can correct what you think might be wrong in the answer.

Comment: @vbence: I didn't downvote ur answer honestly and I read ur example but didn't get how to use it after getting the filesize.

Comment: +1 Good write-up. One reminder though : using Range will only work on servers that support partial downloads (not all of them are configured to do that). And you could use `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RANGE, '1024000-2048000');` instead of sending the range with CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.

Comment: @Kiara You have to replace the number in the `Range` line. It works like *From-To*. So if you want to get the last 128 bytes then the second number must be ($filesize - 1) and the first ($filesize - 129).

Comment: @wimvds Thanks, I changed my example code. Also added `max` not to get negative offsets on files < 128 bytes.

Comment: If you want to read till the end you don't even need to specify the end of the range - ie, just using `max (0, $filesize - 128) . '-'` as value for the range should work as well.