# Resumable and partial download with PHP curl or similar?

Tags: php, curl, download, p2p

Is is possible to resume downloading a partially downloaded file with curl or similar? I mean, let's say we have this big dbdump.sql file on a `http` or `ftp` server which is 1 GB in size; could I somehow tell this server *please send from the file from byte **x** to byte **y***?

For simplicity's sake, what I'm looking for, with this question, does not include joining the downloaded chunks; rather just downloading the chunks and saving each as a septate file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
curl_setopt ($obj, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ("Range: bytes=1024000-2048000"));
```

This will work for HTTP only of course.

Comment: Thanks really. Would it make a difference when the file is binary, not ascii?

Comment: HTTP is binary-friendly, so no distinction at all. (Range was introduced in HTTP/1.1, so very-very old servers may not support it).